# HDFS WebUI Kerberos Authentication failed by credential can't be found from IE

Tags: windows, hadoop, authentication, hdfs, kerberos

I setup my HDFS service with kerberos authenticaiton, that's the configuration:

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.http.filter.initializers</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.security.AuthenticationFilterInitializer</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.http.authentication.type</name>
    <value>kerberos</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.http.authentication.simple.anonymous.allowed</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.http.authentication.signature.secret.file</name>
    <value>/opt/hadoop/hdfs/default/etc/hadoop/hadoop-http-auth-signature-secret</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.http.authentication.kerberos.principal</name>
    <value>HTTP/192.168.47.143@CLOUD.LOCAL</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.http.authentication.kerberos.keytab</name>y4
    <value>/opt/hadoop/hdfs/default/etc/hadoop/HTTP.keytab</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.http.authentication.cookie.domain</name>y4
    <value>CLOUD.LOCAL</value>
</property>
```

I'm able to test the authentication from Linux environment by run:

> $ kinit "HTTP/192.168.47.143@CLOUD.LOCAL"
>
> $ curl -k -v -u "HTTP/192.168.47.143@CLOUD.LOCAL" --negotiate https://...:50470

This returns good contents.

But when I tried to access from Windows IE, it returns:

> GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos credentails)

I already copied /etc/krb5.conf from the server to C:\Windows\krb5.ini and added the hostname to the security zone. What else should I do for the IE to recognize where to find the key?

I even tried to install MIT Kerberos application (http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Configuring+Kerberos+Authentication+for+Windows) to enable the authentication environment, but it still doesn't work, I have no idea now.

Comment: Download Chrome or Firefox, and find the config switch to enable **GSSAPI** i.e. the Linux / Java protocol for Kerberos. Microsoft products only support SSPI, which is its proprietary protocol. Won't work with Hadoop which is 100% Java.

Comment: Similar issue with `curl`: the Windows version supports SSPI only while the 'nix versions support GSSAPI only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows clients by default don't need a C:\Windows\krb5.ini to negotiate Kerberos.  Though you would need it, if you were trying to perform some advance procedures such as validating a Kerberos keytab on the Windows system itself.  Going forward, it doesn't hurt to keep that file in place now that you have it there.  I think the problem really has to do with IE security zone settings.  It might be something you might have missed - as this can be tricky.

1. Add `http://192.168.47.143` and `*.cloud.local` to the IE *Local Intranet* zone on your client machine.
2. Ensure that Windows credentials are configured to be sent to the remote server in the Intranet Zone (this is the default).
3. Under the IE Advanced tab the "Enable Integrated Windows Authentication" box must be checked.
4. I would clear out IE Temporary Internet Files, and then run `klist purge`, and then restart IE before testing again.

Note that Kerberos works best with host names.  Best Practice is to avoid using IP addresses.  With Kerberos, clients have to be in the same domain as the target resource *unless* (1) a working, verifiable trust is in place between the domains, and (2) the target resource must be ACL'd allowing the client to access.  Otherwise the token could come across as NTLM, in which case the SPNEGO library will deem it to be a "defective token".

Comment: Hi Heron, very appreciate your reply, I already add IP and hostname to the security zone, and Integrated Windows Authentication is enabled as well. but it doesn't help. for the step 2, I don't know how to config the credential, the default logon user is not the one be used for hdfs singin, how I can let IE know which user should be chosen? My Windows AD domain is different to the hdfs kerberos realm, I believe this maybe the point. BTW, klist purge returns 0 ticket.

Comment: Not sure what I changed, the error message now is: "GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)"

Comment: With Kerberos, clients have to be in the same domain as the target resource *unless* (1) a working, verifiable trust is in place between the domains, and (2) the target resource must be ACL'd allowing the client to access.  Otherwise the token could come across as NTLM, in which case the SPNEGO library will deem it to be a "defective token".  I added this comment to my answer.

Comment: That's too complicate. I'm giving up kerberos authentication and changing to Knox now, Thank you, Heron.

Comment: Could you expand on your 2nd point? I'm not sure what you mean by "target resource must be ACL'd". I'm in a similar situation and when I debug cURL, it seems like the Windows client is sending a NTLM token even though I have a ticket cache with `KRB5CCNAME` env variable pointing to it.

Comment: Hi @ejang, I think this should be a new question.

Comment: Hello @T-Heron , I have posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262588/how-to-specify-which-kerberos-credential-to-use-for-sspi?noredirect=1#comment71698055_42262588 if you would like to take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @ejang, I am not sure.  If I run across something, I will let you know.